# Excel - Return adjacent value from multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a report structured where I need to return the value directly to the right of the cell.

```
Example:
A   B      C   D   E   F    G  H
1  Red     4 Green 6 Orange 7 Pink
2  Black   5 Blue
3  Yellow  

Desired Output
1 Red
2 Black
3 Yellow
4 Green
5 Blue
6 Orange
7 Pink
```

In total I need to look through about 40 columns of data.  One solution is to do a IFERROR(VLOOKUP), this would require about 40 VLOOKUPS.

I want to check if there's an easy way to search a matrix for a value then return the value next to it.

Comment: 40 vlookups is not a lot in the grand scheme of things. Only when they get complex is when you would see a performance issue.

Comment: Will your data always be number | word or was that just for the example?

Comment: Always number and word combination.  I may just go with VLOOKUPs, but wanted to check if there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your original table into your Desired Output using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

- On the Data Tab select Get&Transform from Table/Range (this might be different in different versions)
- Add an index column.
- Select the Index column and then `UNPIVOT other columns`
- Add another, zero-based index column
- Select this new Index column, then add Integer/Divide (by 2) column.
- Again with the same Index column selected, add Modulo (by 2) column.
- Remove the zero-based Index column you added second.
- Select the Modulo column and Pivot

  - For the Values column select Value (default name of the column with all the data
  - Under `Advanced` option select `Don't Aggregate`
- Remove the extraneous columns
- Rename the pivoted columns from `0 | 1` to whatever you want (I left them alone)
- Sort the rows by the number column

All the steps can be done from the UI, but below is the **M Code** which you can just paste into the Advanced Editor, if you want.  You will have to change the Source table name to match whatever is in your Excel.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", Int64.Type}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", Int64.Type}, {"Column8", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index.1", 0, 1),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index.1], 2), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Integer-Division", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index.1], 2), type number),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Modulo",{"Index.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US")[Modulo]), "Modulo", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index", "Integer-Division"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns2",{{"0", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows",{{"0", Int64.Type}, {"1", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have Excel 2019 (365) so please give it a try with and without the `@` symbol before `ROW` and `COLUMN`

Here is the formula with the `@` symbols:

```
=@INDEX(Matrix;SUMPRODUCT((Matrix=A7)*ROW(Matrix))-@ROW(Matrix)+1;SUMPRODUCT((Matrix=A7)*COLUMN(Matrix))-@COLUMN(Matrix)+1+1)
```

No `@` symbols:

```
=INDEX(Matrix;SUMPRODUCT((Matrix=A7)*ROW(Matrix))-ROW(Matrix)+1;SUMPRODUCT((Matrix=A7)*COLUMN(Matrix))-COLUMN(Matrix)+1+1)
```

Based on this setup

[image: Data set up]

**Result**

[image: Result]

Note: this would only work if there are no duplicates in the matrix

Let me know if it works